# How to load a mat file from a google storage bucket in jupyter notebook

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, mat

I am trying to train a model on ~16gb of image data. I need to import an `annotations.mat` file from my Cloud Storage bucket. However, since `loadmat` requires a file path, I am not sure how to import a Google Storage bucket path. I tried to create a `pickle` file of the mat data, but Jupyter Notebook crashes.

Current attempt:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id')
blob = bucket.get_blob('path/to/annotations.pkl')
# crashes here
print(blob.download_as_string())
```

I want to do something like:

```
import scipy.io as sio

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id')

matfile = sio.loadmat(buket_path + 'path/to/annotations.pkl')
```

Does anyone know how to load a mat file from a Cloud Storage bucket?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any direct import from a `blob object` to a `mat` file in python. However there is a workaround that would solve the problem: instead of importing directly the blob object and read it through `loadmat`, create a temporary file and use the path for `loadmat` function.

In order to reproduce the scenario, I followed the [Google Cloud Storage python example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) (uploaded a [mat file](https://github.com/fsprojects/matprovider/tree/master/data) to a bucket). The following python code downloads the blob object, reads it using `loadmat`, and finally it removes the file created:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import scipy.io


bucket_name = '<BUCKET NAME>'
mat_file_path = '<PATH>/<MAT FILENAME>'
temp_mat_filename = 'temp.mat'

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(mat_file_path)
# Download mat file to temporary mat file
blob.download_to_filename(temp_mat_filename)
# Get mat object from temporary mat file
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(temp_mat_filename)
# Remove temp_mat_filename file
# import os
# os.remove(temp_mat_filename)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

This code describe the uploading object to the bucket.
I add the url where you can find more info:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects.